Looking for a Star Wars Legends novel where Gamorreans were used as guinea pigs
I remember reading a Star Wars Legends story in the late 1990s/early 2000s where Gamorreans were used as guinea pigs. They were imprisoned in a lab (I believe it was inside a dungeon), and one or more mad scientists conducted tests on the Gamorreans for malicious purposes. They were testing a medication or a poison, I believe. I did some research and discovered in Aaron Allston's Star Wars Legends novel "X-Wing: Wraith Squadron" (1998) that one of the most notable Gamorreans named Voort sa Binring, nicknamed "Piggy", who was a member of Wraith Squadron, was biochemically altered as part of Project Chubar by Binring Biomedical Product to bring his attention span and intelligence more in line with Humans But this is not the novel I'm searching for.

This was not the book where a scientist found a way to transform people into Gamorreans via a poison and a sound prompt?

@FuzzyBoots - No. It wasn't. I believe the scientist (or scientist) considered the Gamorreans expendables for the experiments.

In Michael A. Stackpole's book X-Wing: Wedge's Gamble Gamorrean prisoners are used to develop a virus. Could this be the book you're thinking of?

Derricote led him deeper into the laboratory complex and through a doorway into a stainless-steel corridor. Transparisteel windows lined the walls and gave them views of detention cells with one or two individuals in them. On the left were piggish Gamorreans-naked, as were the squid-headed Quarren on the right side-looking miserable in their clinically spare environs. Those nearest the doorway through which they entered appeared relatively normal-though they were such a sight that Loor couldn't bring himself to study them in any great detail.
"You will notice the transparisteel windows are triple-paned. That central sheet is reflective on their side, so they cannot see us. The walls between the cells are soundproofed. We found that necessary to maintain order."
"I see," Loor said, but he really saw no need for security precautions.
The first few Gamorreans were placid, though they did seem to know people might be observing them through the windows, so they sat in such a way that they preserved their modesty. Farther along they appeared to be in some sort of a stupor. Their black eyes had become quite glassy and fixed on one point. They just lay there, barely moving, in whatever position they seemed to find themselves, no matter how uncomfortable.
Loor did notice a splotchiness on the Gamorreans' flesh. Angry black boils seemed to radiate out a spider's web of lines that connected them one to another. One creature had a boil on his tongue and several others showed them on the bottoms of their feet. Loor assumed the boils were painful since what little movement he did see seemed to be an attempt to relieve pressure on them.
He also noticed these Gamorreans seemed very dry. Mucus and saliva did not decorate their faces the way it normally did. Clearly the creatures were sick, but Loor somehow took that to be the most telling sign of their disease.
Then he saw the final-stage patients.


Yes! That was it! Thank you @John Rennie for catching it. After reading part of the novel, Now, I remember those poor Gamorrians and other species pulled from Invisec (the Alien Protection Zone) for experiments. Thanks again!

This could be the 1995 novel Children of the Jedi. The plot revolves around the autonomous Imperial dreadnaught Eye of Palpatine, which by the time of the story has been roving around, capturing, and indoctrinating various sentient species, including Gamorreans.
From Wookieepedia's summary:

Upon activation, the Eye of Palpatine attempted to fulfill its programming by picking up its Imperial stormtrooper contingent. But, after so many years, the troops had disappeared, except for Triv Pothman, one of 45 troopers left on the Gamorrean colony Pzob, who survived the bloodshed brought on by the various warring Gamorrean tribes.
Undaunted, the Eye went after any sentient beings found in the appropriate locations. It began grabbing groups of prisoners from various species located on the enlisted worlds. Soon the Eye was filled with numerous species including Talz, Affytechans, Jawas, Kitonaks, Tusken Raiders, Tripods, and Gamorreans. They were all brainwashed into thinking they were Imperial stormtroopers.
—Eye of Palpatine on Wookieepedia

The above article also includes this illustration from Star Wars Galaxy Magazine 3:




No. That's not the novel. I just read the passages of the novel about the indoctrination of Gamorreans to think as stormtrooper persona and as I also mentioned to FuzzyBoots, the Gamorreans were used as guinea pig testing them with harmful things. Also, the place where the experiments took place was a kind of a dungeon probably in underground places on a planet and not in a spaceship. Thank you anyway for your response.
